# P-JAX headers not showing up at PHP server even though everything works as it should?

Tags: php, pjax, request-headers

I'm at a loss here.

I've implemented [MoOx pjax](https://github.com/MoOx/pjax) on a web server with a PHP backend and everything works great, pages load as they should - no problems there whatsoever!

Now I've come to handling auth states server side I'm having an issue as even though the browser console declares that it's sending the following headers along :

```
X-PJAX: true
X-PJAX-Selectors: ["#main"]
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

I'm not receiving any of them server side in the request, making it impossible to determine a `pjax` request from anything else like a regular `GET` or `POST`.

Do I have to set something up in PHP to be able to receive or see these headers?

I've tried a bunch of different ways of reading the headers including :

```
print_r($_SERVER);
print_r(getallheaders());
print_r(apache_request_headers());
```

But the elusive `P-JAX` ones are nowhere to be seen!

If it's relevant I'm running Apache with a reverse nginx proxy.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you found any solution for this

Comment: No I didn't sadly. Everything I tried failed. In the end I took a different approach to validating what I needed to validate.